# configuring my Kurento Media Server over Public IP

Tags: configuration, webrtc, kurento

I try to setup a Kurento Media Server in my Ubuntu 14.04 64x, have configure my system with Turn server from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/8Qrz6P1KYxA) and after that I install my KMS from [This doc](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/StreamOriented_-_Installation_and_Administration_Guide) When i try to find my Listening ports  using 
`sudo netstat -atnp | grep LISTEN` commandnd i found the following `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5941          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1773/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1634/dnsmasq

tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1297/dnsmasq

tcp        0      0 192.168.0.2:3478        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6140/turnserver 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1117/sshd

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5642/cupsd

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1256/postgres

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      791/smbd

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5766          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6140/turnserver 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      791/smbd

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1117/sshd

tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      5642/cupsd

tcp6       0      0 :::8888                 :::*                    LISTEN      1683/kurento-media-
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      1256/postgres

tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                    LISTEN      791/smbd

tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                    LISTEN      791/smbd`
 But I am not able to find my public ip on it.
Please guide me how to configure the media server for my public ip. I am Using a Wifi Router for my internet connection.

Comment: Could you post here your WebRTC endpoint configuration, as read from the KMS log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're behind a router, your computer has no direct way of knowing your public IP. To find your public IP, load up a browser and ask Google what your IP is. If your OS has is a CLI only server, use this one-liner I yanked from https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip.

```
curl ipecho.net/plain ; echo
```